# How do I get Cargo to save the name/version of a package to the "[dependencies]" section of my "Cargo.toml" file?

Tags: rust, package, installation, rust-cargo

Today I spent more time than I should have trying to figure out why my project wasn't building, only to find out that I forgot to include the following crate:

```
[dependencies]
glob = "~0.3.0"
```

I'd like to avoid making this mistake again by having Cargo add the name/version of a package to the `[dependencies]` section of my `Cargo.toml` file **when I install the package**.

To give you a better example of what I mean, in `NPM` if you run:

```
npm install --save-dev glob
```

It'd save the name/version of the `glob` package to `dependencies` section of the `package.json` file.

How do I do this in Cargo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a crate called [`cargo-edit`](https://github.com/killercup/cargo-edit) which expands `cargo` with subcommands `add`, `rm` and `upgrade` to act similarly to how `npm install` (and other package managers) do:

```
# install cargo-edit
cargo install cargo-edit

# add crate "glob"
cargo add glob
```

The resulting `Cargo.toml` file would look like this:

```
[dependencies]
glob = "0.3.0"
```

The crate will be downloaded and built the next time you run a regular Cargo command (e.g. `cargo build`, `cargo run`, `cargo test`).